# Render.com problem when deploying my Node.js application

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, deployment, render.com

currently I'm deploying a full stack Node.js application to Render.com. It seems like Render is not connecting to MySQL database. In vsCode, everything works fine but after deploying my application, database is not working and users cannot register or login to system. (I'm using MySQL workbench, not Xampp by the way)

**Error is**

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
Feb 7 06:52:58 PM      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
Feb 7 06:52:58 PM    errno: -111,
Feb 7 06:52:58 PM    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
Feb 7 06:52:58 PM    syscall: 'connect',
Feb 7 06:52:58 PM    address: '127.0.0.1',
Feb 7 06:52:58 PM    port: 3306,
Feb 7 06:52:58 PM    fatal: true
Feb 7 06:52:58 PM  }
```

My application uses port 3307, MySQL uses port 3306, why am i getting this error ? What should i do handle this error? A user can register and login the system in localhost but cannot login after deploying Render. This is because the application works in locahost ? This is my first time deploying a project. Thanks for your help

Edit: Front-end part can deploy but I think there is problem in database connection. I have no idea.